# Backup throws permission error

Tags: sql-server, backup

I'm trying to backup SQL Server database to upload it to my database server. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, Database -> Tasks -> Back Up...
And I got the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 300)

Any idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that for the database you're trying to back up, you have at least the *db_backupoperator* database role assigned to the user that's trying to run the backup. 
That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
 USE MASTER
    GO
    GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO User
    ;
```

Here User is , which you are runnig the query in SSMS.

[For further ref from pinal Blog "SQL SERVER – Error Fix: Msg 300, VIEW SERVER STATE"](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/10/12/sql-server-error-fix-msg-300-view-server-state/)

Answer (score -2):

What is happening is simple - read the error message. The user you are connected to the database server with has not enough permissions.

Database backup in SQL Server requires quite some permission - you likely only got permissions assigned to the database "as needed" and that is not enough.

Comment: So how can I get the permissions? I logged in with the SQL permissions and runned SQL Managemente studio as an administrator.

Comment: To answer that - who are you (for the database server)? What account do you log into the database server with. SQL Server does not care what you run management studio under - it cares about the permission of the user you connect with (from sql server point of view). You need ad least backup permission (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1015169-391-1.aspx) - db_backupoperator

Comment: Sorry Im very new to database management, I just installed SQL Server and proceed with all the standard configurations, to be able to create a database and link it to Umbraco. Im logging in with SQL Server authentication.